# Jaspersoft: Dropdownlist in iReport

Tags: drop-down-menu, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I am trying to create a parameter which should be a dropdownlist. I need to let the use choose from 3 different values.

Is this possible? Or will I have to code one myself in Java? If so, how can this be done?

I'm using iReport Designer 4.0.2.

Thanks!

Comment: If I am not mistaken you are referring to **cell-validation-> list (drop-down)** in excel sheets right.

Comment: Well, I am trying to create an input control or something like that (On jasperServer). I found where I can create it, but I can't find how I can dynamically fill the list. I can only enter them by hand.

Perhaps this is a stupid question, but I'm new to Jaspersoft. Just started to expirement a bit.

Comment: @Tjekkles, do you want your dropdownlist to appear in JasperServer or in iReport? Implementing an input control is slightly different depending on which.

Comment: I'd prefer on the jasperServer (Because when you implement it it will also be on a server, so it will be the same as on the jasperServer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with JasperServer.
This articles should help you:

[Cascade Parameter Reports in IReport & Jasper Server](http://qants.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/jasper-reports-cascade-parameter-reports-in-ireport-jasper-server-3-7-5/)
 
[JasperServer Guide](http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-7-0/JasperServer-CE-User-Guide.pdf)
[Adding Report Units from JRXML Files](http://help.jaspersoft.com/Content/JasperServer-Help-Book/Adding_Report_Units_from.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I followed your tutorial (not cascade but just one field). It works locally, but when I run it on the server, I can choose between some checkboxes or so, but when I check one (or all) it just always gives the same result... 53 blanc pages. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I think this is query bug or filter does not effect report

Comment: You can read JasperServer Guide. Chapter 4.3.3 Adding input controls